# Can you include a search input in an Ebay listing design?

Tags: ebay-api

Does anybody know if you can have a search input on an Ebay listing? I'm not talking about an Ebay Shop as I know you can for them.

Comment: Going out on a limb and assuming you mean a product listing, as opposed to an eBay Store page.

Comment: Yes David! I know you can for the store. Not sure about product listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!

And here are a few fine examples just to prove the point:

- http://www.ebay.com/itm/151439589823
- http://www.ebay.com/itm/151354090252

Here's a good example. Note that you must replace http://stores.ebay.com/storeId/ with your own shop URL.:

The below should be placed inside of your template source:

```
<form action="http://stores.ebay.com/storeId/" target="_blank">
   <input name="_nkw" placeholder="Search by brand or keyword...">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Also note that `target="_blank"` is vital, otherwise the listing, which eBay houses within an iframe, will continue to reload within the iframe.

Comment: Cheers mate... this really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can work with just change the store name

```
<div id="SearchBox"><form action="http://stores.ebay.com/STORENAME/" id="ga_search" target="_top" style="padding-top: 54px;">
            <input type="text" style="width: 205px; height:40px; display: block; float:left;border: none;outline: none;background: transparent;padding-left: 20px;font-size: 18px;" class="searchbox" name="_nkw" value="">
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" style="height:40px; display: block; border-style: none; float:left; background: none; cursor: pointer;padding:10px 22px;" class="searchbox_submit" value=" "></form>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this method is correct, it is completely unnecessary to include all of the inline CSS, as it has no bearing on the functionality of the search form. There is also an additional, unclosed div that will harm the formatting of the listing page.